# Wizard Portlet with JSF and Richfaces on Tomcat

Tags: jsf, ant, liferay, richfaces, portlet

I want to create a simple richfaces wizard as a portlet, so i used the example from [here](http://showcase.richfaces.org/richfaces/component-sample.jsf?demo=togglePanel&sample=wizard&skin=blueSky). When i insert that files into my project and start the liferay server the main view is shown correctly but the next button does not do anything except refreshing the page.

I'm using the 4.3.2 Final of richfaces components inside ant/ivy build

Answer (score 1):

My guess is because that showcase example has the ajax switch type. Since you are making a server request to determine the next state I think it will always be the one you are on unless you manage it on the server or if you use the default client state. i.e. change:

```
<rich:togglePanel switchType="ajax">
```

to use the default client state:

```
<rich:togglePanel>
```

Comment: Thanks for the fast response. I tried the server and client switch but it doesn't make any difference

Comment: I also tried to insert the wstep1, wstep2 directly into the view.xhtml and to add a standard constructor into Profile ManagedBean, but with no success

Comment: Do you have any rich:message tags on your page? If there are any validation error messages being triggered you wouldn't be able to toggle panels. Also add a4j:log component to your page to see any error messages.

Comment: yay! it works now, thanks for the tip.. somehow there was a problem creating the main view but nevertheless it rendered the components ...  now I use <f:view component and <h:head>, <h:body> to create the main view